How to be Jewish
How to convert to Judaism as a female? I don't have access to going to any temple or shul. I also want to do this online as well. Is it cheap or free too?

If you are involved with a Jewish partner and are converting for that reason it may complicate things

A serious conversion is going to take serious work. There may be places that claim to offer something online ... they're not well-respected.
As Ruth said to Naomi, *your people are my people, and your G-d is my G-d." Conversion involves accepting the laws/rituals, and also accepting one's lot as a part of the Jewish people. If you're not affiliating with a synagogue, how are you going to live a Jewish life or connect to the Jewish people? (Never mind -- how are you going to see in action how these laws/rituals are actually lived?)
The answers here default to Orthodox Judaism unless specifically asked otherwise, but I don't think any major denomination is going to treat a free, online conversion as very valid.
Basically -- if you're not putting much into this, you're not going to get much out of it.
On the other end of the spectrum, if you want an Orthodox conversion that will be universally accepted, then you'll have to make contact with a synagogue, make plans to move within walking distance of it and attend regularly, start taking lessons, keeping kosher, and the like. After living the life for 1--2 years, if it's clear to the rabbi you're sincere (and you understand what you're getting yourself into), then the final step would be a declaring your acceptance to a panel of rabbis, plus a ceremonial dunk in a ritual bath.
(Now if you live close enough to a synagogue to walk there eh, let's say every other week, it may be you can take some of the conversion lessons on Zoom, but you'll still be checking in "in real life" every so often. It's not an "online conversion.")
The rabbis aren't going to charge you for the conversion, but relocating to near an Orthodox synagogue and keeping kosher may be more expensive.
